# Ajax web chat keep state without iframe

Tags: javascript, html, ajax

I'm developing a site on which I'll have a chat as well as a webcam chat (which is flash). My first thought was to contain the entire site within an iframe to make sure the chat keeps its state and doesn't abort the webcam chat. Thinking about it a bit more I felt that doing it is a massive hack as well as not very pleasant. Reading up on it, it would seem that google does not index frames either. This means that the solution is not a good one.

Other than having javascript update the entire content of the site (á Twitter), are there any other proper solutions in which I can keep the state of my chat but still keep the site proper.

I hope the question is understandable!